# How do parenthetical if-statements work? E.g. "he is a happy, if quiet, boy."

Tags: conditionals, parentheticals

I might even be using it wrong in the example. How are these statements usually structured, and what's the implication of using this construct ("he is a happy, if quiet, boy") rather than something more straightforward? The examples I can think of usually seem to have a adjective in the parenthetical that is somewhat counter to the main statement.

Can it be a verb instead of an adjective ("he is a quiet, if amused, boy")?

Sorry if this has been answered, it's a very difficult thing to search for without knowing the name for it (if there is one).

Comment: 'If' here is a synonym for 'albeit', though the latter is getting old-fashioned. It's a mitigator. 'He's a happy boy, though I' should add that's also quiet.' // 'Amused' doesn't work attributively with 'boy' anyway: *'He's an amused boy.'  But 'He's a nasty if talented player' is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try rearranging the sentence like this:

> "Although he is quiet, he is a happy boy."

The word "although" shows that you need a contrast there. This if statement is simply another way of ordering the idea. It's a question of style. That sounds like something you would find in a book, a narrative style. But it could be speech. Imagine:

> "Tyler's entrance to the race is a welcome, if unexpected
>   development..."

Notice we're still talking about a third party, like commentary (narrative style). If I reword it:

> "Tyler's entrance to the race is an unexpected, but welcome
>   development..."

It now sounds more like speech and less stilted.

Comment: I think you should remove the comma or put another comma after _welcome_. I'd remove the comma.

Comment: It's not a complete sentence. It continues, as the ellipsis indicates. That is why the comma was placed there.